# How to use evaluateInCell with cell of IFERROR funcation?

Tags: apache-poi

set  cell  Formula :

```
IFERROR("FY"&YEAR("2019/04/26")-"6","NA")
```

[image]

look cellType:

[image]

evaluateFormulaCell:

[image]

get cell value：

[image]

but :

[image]

and  I try this:

[image: 20190828120047_d42379290f9a70bc83ababeee2a18c14.png]

update:

```
@Test
    public void ifERRORTest() {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("1");
        Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
        cell.setCellFormula("IFERROR(\"FY\"&2019-\"1\",\"NA\")");
//        cell.setCellFormula("YEAR(\"2018-01-01\")");
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
        System.out.println(cell.getCellType());
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
```

this is work. so YEAR("2019/01/01") not work

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611175/poi-formula-evaluater-iferror


but  my version is 4.1.0

Comment: Please help us to help you! Please don't post your code as picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your evaluation problem is not about `IFERROR` but about [YEAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/year-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9). The description clearly states:

> Syntax
>
> YEAR(serial_number)
>
> The YEAR function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> **Serial_number** Required. The date of the year you want to find. Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as
>   results of other formulas or functions. For example, use
>   DATE(2008,5,23) for the 23rd day of May, 2008. Problems can occur if
>   dates are entered as text.

But your formula uses the string "2019/04/26" as parameter in `YEAR`. Do using `YEAR(DATE(2019,4,26))` and it will work.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class ExcelEvaluateIFERROR {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
   //cell.setCellFormula("IFERROR(\"FY\"&YEAR(\"2019/04/26\")-\"6\",\"NA\")"); // will not work
   cell.setCellFormula("IFERROR(\"FY\"&YEAR(DATE(2019,4,26))-\"6\",\"NA\")"); // works
   FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
   CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell);
   System.out.println(cellValue);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```